# Format date and time in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, datetime-format

I want to format time like 12:45:34 using `GWT` `setFormat` method. I am giving input format like this.

```
startDate.getPropertyEditor().setFormat( "MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

but output is not having seconds in it. Could anyone please suggest where I am missing.

Comment: can you tell us startDate is object of which class?

Comment: please provide full class name. It seems to me [DateField.java](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/DateField.html)  is GXT class.

Comment: yes , DateField.java class of GXT only I have used. thanks

Comment: First of all things are working as expected with gxt 3x for me using this lines of code DateField df = new DateField(new DateTimePropertyEditor("MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); secondly it does not make any sense to me to show time part in date field, you should think of using TimeField for it.

Comment: Thanks Ajax, actually it's a project requirement to use a particular duration , for that i need time in the date field.

Comment: So above line of code working for you? As I believe you are working with gxt2x.

Comment: No, but i think some other code error is there. thanks for the help